# List сущьностей из бд Criteria API

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

```
public Long userNotificationsCount(UUID userId) {
    CriteriaBuilder criteria = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Long> query = criteria.createQuery(Long.class);
    Root<NotificationDto> root = query.from(NotificationDto.class);
    query.select(criteria.count(root));
    Predicate predicate = criteria.and(
            criteria.or(
                    criteria.equal(root.get("userId"), userId),
                    criteria.isNull(root.get("userId"))),
            criteria.equal(root.get("status"), NotificationStatus.NEW.getValue()));
    query.where(predicate);
    return entityManager.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
}
```

Нужно. сделать метод на подобии вышеприведенного но возвращать он должен list не понимаю как нужна помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем вы пишите `entityManager.createQuery(query).getSingleResult()`, если хотите `List`? `getSingleResult()` — переводиться как "получить одиночный результат". В целом, он и делает это. Возвращает одиночный результат.

Используйте `entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList()` и будет Вам `List`